# How can the table attached below be more perfect?

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xNx3.png)
hello,
I've written a code for "Digital Score card". Everything is fine but the scorecard is looking Odd. I mean the elements in columns A,B,C,D are arranged irregularly. Is there any code to make the elements look like a Straight line?(Program written using JAVA)
thanks in advance.

Comment: Add spacing between the score prints using `\t` instead of spaces. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html for more information.

Comment: Please try to paste the code showing how you have done it. This will help people in giving you relevant ideas. Right now what you are asking can be done in many ways. Try to print out in a table/grid format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you look at the `String.format` method's [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) and the `Formatter` [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

The `Formatter` class can do things like format a number left or right justified in a fixed width field.  You should be able to use this to line up the fields in your table into columns.  (Read the descriptions of the `flags` and `width` in the Format String Syntax section.)

Using TAB characters ( `'\t'` ) is another alternative, but it has the problem that TAB means different things when displayed in different contexts; e.g. typically 4 spaces in Windows versus 8 spaces in Linux and Mac.

Answer (score 0):

You could eventually setup a fixed "cell" size of for example 15 characters for a label and 6 for a column.
Such a function would be:
`str_out = fill_whitespace_until(str_in, nb_char=15, direction='right')`
With `nb_char int: nb of characters` and 
`direction str: {'left', 'right'} either insert or append the whitespaces to choose alignment`

Before printing the fields, pass the variables to this function and it should be consistent and well aligned at the end.